# How to make sure hub connection when page is hard reloaded

Tags: c#, signalr

I have studied all the documentation of SignalR and implemented it in my project and it's working perfectly but when I hard reload my page then the hub connection does not establish and connection can not be obtained. I have also tried a timeout function to wait for $.connection.hub.start().done() to complete.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { 
                chat.server.aaaaa();
            })
        }, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's very late to answer this question but it might be helpful for others. This might be because of the rendering of view on the page you are rendering some images that take time to render and creating